# dc.js types in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, dc.js

I have a problem with types when I use dc.js version 4.2.7. In order to solve it I installed what seems to be the default types module for dc.js with the following command:

*Install command I used*

```
npm i @types/dc
```

My code works correctly in javascript. However in typescript I either struggle with the types or when I use `@types/dc` it won't let me import the chart classes.

It seems to me that the types module is outdated because even though it doesn't lets me import the chart classes it does let me import the old function based API that dc.js used in older versions.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Yes it is very likely that the Definitely Typed module for dc.js is out of date. It is maintained separately by external volunteers, and it [looks like it may never have been updated](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/dc) for dc@4. If you are using Typescript, you might try the dc-v5 branch of dc.js, which has been fully translated. It has many improvements and API changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some search I found that what the user Gordon in the comment above was saying is indeed true. `@types/dc` for dc v4 is outdated and it won't work correctly.

A quick, dirty way of at least handling the types warnings would be to simply declare the module like so:

*dc.d.ts*

```
declare module "dc";
```

Some where accessible where your typescript transpiler can access it